# JavaScript- getting the properties of an object, by clicking an image stored in an array within the object, on the HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have the following JS object:

```
var sources = {
        assets: [],
        liabilities: [],
        income: [],
        expenditure: []
    }
```

as you can see, this object contains a number of JS arrays. I've added a number of images from a hidden section in my HTML to these arrays using lines such as:

```
sources.assets[0] = document.getElementById("building").src,
sources.assets[1] = document.getElementById("chair").src,
sources.liabilities[0] = document.getElementById("burger").src,
sources.liabilities[1] = document.getElementById("chips").src,
```

What I now want to be able to do is: when a click (or `mousedown`) is detected on one of these images on the canvas, I want to find out which array that image belongs to within the object, and save the value of that array (i.e. the array name- assets/ liabilities, etc) to a variable.

But I'm not sure how I can find this out... I tried printing the contents of the properties of an image when a click was detected on one, using the line:

```
console.log("value of variable obj:" + output + ". Shape is " + obj.shape + ". index is " + obj.shape.index);
```

But that just gave me the following printout in the console

```
value of variable obj:shape: [object Object]; pixel: [object Uint8ClampedArray]; . Shape is [object Object]. index is 7
```

in the console.

I am using a local copy of the KineticJS library to draw the images to the canvas, and I know that the variable `obj` is one used within the `mousedown` function in the kineticJS library.

The user is required to drag each of the 'draggable' images to their corresponding description box (located on the canvas).

What I'd like to know is how I can find out which array the image that has been clicked on belongs to, so that I can then compare the name of that array to the name of the image that the user drags the 'clicked' image to: if they are the same, then the user has dragged the image to the correct description box, and if not, then they've made an incorrect selection.

Does anyone know how I would find out which array the clicked image belongs to?

Comment: Please log `output` and `obj` so that we can see which properties they have, their stringifications do not help us.

Comment: That's what I've done... the log of `output` displays `shape: [object Object]; pixel: [object Uint8ClampedArray];`, and the log of `obj` displays `[object Object]`...

Comment: No, please reread my comment. Use `console.dir`, or `console.log(output, obj)` and expand the properties!

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating your kineticJS images, set the "name" property of each image to the type of image it is like this:

```
var chair = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 140,
      y: 20,
      name: chair,
      ...more...
```

Then when an image is selected you use the selected object's .getName() to retrieve "chair".

From there you do your array lookup and all is good...

So you're using the "name" property kind of like a css classname.